Why does my merging k lists program shows time limit exceeded error in LeetCode?
I was doing qn.23 in Leetcode,  which is merging k sorted Linked lists. I used an iteration approach, checked for minimum value in the List[] lists, and then updated it to my ans ListNode. But, for some reason that I don't know, I am getting time limit exceeded error.
LeetCode provided this description of ListNode:
---
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
---

My code looks as follows:
public class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
        ListNode ans = null;
        ListNode last = null;

        while (!emptyCheck(lists)&&lists.length!=0) {
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int minIndex = -1;

            // Find the minimum value among the current heads of the lists
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                if (lists[i] != null && lists[i].val < min) {
                    min = lists[i].val;
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }

            if (minIndex != -1) {
                // Create a new node with the minimum value
                ListNode newNode = new ListNode(min);
                if (ans == null) {
                    ans = newNode;
                    last = newNode;
                } else {
                    last.next = newNode;
                    last = newNode;
                }

                // Move to the next node in the list with the minimum value
                lists[minIndex] = lists[minIndex].next;
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }

    // Check if any list has remaining nodes
    static boolean emptyCheck(ListNode[] lists) {
        for (ListNode list : lists) {
            if (list != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Do you get Time Out Error for all tests or just some?  If just some, are you able to see what is in the lists parameter? What is different about those test cases?

Just for clarification, the first codition check in while loop, if list in lists are not null, it returns true which turns to false with !emptyCheck(lists), how does it get within the while block?

Your code goes into an infinite loop for the test case in example 3: [[]]. In this case, lists has one element, but that element is an empty list.
Look at this statement: while (!emptyCheck(lists)&&lists.length!=0).
Because lists has an element, lists.length!=0 will be true. That one element will be a empty list. So the for loop in emptyCheck(lists) will have zero iterations. The method will return false. That will cause the whole Boolean expression of the while to be true. The code block subject to the while will execute.
But, under those circumstances, execution will make no changes that will move closer to completion.
Off-topic: For a method that returns a boolean, the name emptyCheck is ambiguous. In my opinion, if a method returns a boolean, it best have a name that begins with is or has or similar. The method name should read like a yes / no question. Rather than emptyCheck, I might have named it hasList.

Thank you, I am still heart broken that I could not find that error even after wasting 3 hours on debugging.
